# IEEE template and caption=false option for subcaption package?

Tags: ieeetran, subcaption

According to the IEEE transactions information (tar file [here](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/IEEEtran.tar) contains IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf along with the class files)

> Axel Sommerfeldt’s modern and actively maintained subcaption.sty package [23] can not be recommended at this time because it does not provide an option to prevent the underlying caption.sty from taking control of main caption formatting away from IEEEtran.

Instead they recommend using subfig invoked like this `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`

Are there any plans to add a `caption=false` flag to `subcaption`? It seems that `subfig` has not been touched since 2005, so I would rather stick with `subcaption` if possible.

EDIT: There is a workaround posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113459/ieeetran-caption-question/113494#113494), but it involves re-defining how captions should be formatted, which seems to partially defeat the purpose of using a supplied style file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: `subcaption` depends heavily on `caption`; there's no way to make it work without it. In my opinion IEEE should rewrite their styles with `caption` and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and for the formatting help Adam. I guess I'll keep using subcaption and include the manual corrections.

Answer (score 18):

An answer [provided by Michael Shell](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/#:%7E:text=subcaption) gives this workaround:

```
\makeatletter
\let\MYcaption\@makecaption
\makeatother

\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\let\@makecaption\MYcaption
\makeatother
```