# Lyx IEEE Transactions Figure Label Nonstandard

Tags: floats, lyx, ieeetran

I am using the IEEE transactions template in lyx and I noticed on the figures instead of saying "Fig.1" or "Fig. 2", the figures are labeled as "Figure 1." or "Figure 2."

I looked at the most recent publications from this journal and the correct method is Fig., not Figure as lyx is outputting.

I am wondering what could be wrong and what I should try. I already went to Document-->Settings-->Document class and double checked it is set to "IEEE Transactions" and Custom: journal.

Comment: Take a look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113459/ieeetran-caption-question

Comment: @percusse, I didn't see how that was helpful. Which part particularly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution via @Werner:

Make sure that you also remove the use of babel in your preamble. That is, under Document > Settings... > Language, select None in terms of the language package to use:

See this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215226/33937) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

ieeetran.cls has

```
\def\figurename{Fig.}
\def\tablename{TABLE}
\@IEEEcompsocconfonly{\def\figurename{Figure}}
```

so should be using `Fig.` except in the IEEE comp soc conf setting. You can always add

```
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
```

to set it back.

Comment: I have this in my lyx preample, and it shows Figure 1. still                % for subfigures/subtables
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}             I also tried commenting out that first line, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following to the preample and it worked correctly:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
```

I referenced this answer:
[Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17490/33937)

I tried following David Carlisle's suggestions of adding `\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}` but that actually didn't work regardless of where I place it in the preamble.  It also caused Lyx to show error messages when I tried compiling to a PDF.