# References section in spanish without babel package

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, spanish

I am working on a document and when using the package `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` I get a lot of errors and warnings. If I don't use it everything is fine. The problem is that the references section is in English "References", when I need it to say "Referencias".

**Is there any way to just change the name of that section?**

The way I place my references is:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

[image]

For example, in this simple code the word references is already in English.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cite{ANoteGI}
\lipsum[45]

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

I want this but without usin babel:

[image]

Comment: You have to provide more information, e. g. document class. Ideally, provide a complete (but minimal)  code.

Comment: Are you using `\documentclass{article}` or `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` in your actual document?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'm using \documentclass{article}

Comment: So, the real problem here is you are getting a lot of errors with `spanish` (please, note warnings are not errors). Try with `\usepackage[spanish, es-sloppy]{babel}` or `\usepackage[spanish, es-minimal]{babel}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A wild guess based on David's answer in [Lyx IEEE Transactions Figure Label Nonstandard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212109).
- I had a look at `IEEEtran.cls`, see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/.
- **Write `\def\refname{Referencias}` before `\begin{document}`.**

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: @nkeLeAdo If it worked then you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark symbol next to the answer.