# IEEEtran bibliography style won't compress in-text citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I cannot get IEEEtran in-text citations to format properly. I am getting citation compressions looking like [1-5] instead of [1]-[5] as it is in IEEE journals. I have bibliographies after each chapter so I'm using  `\usepackage{chapterbib}`. Also, I could only get any citation compression with `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`. Without this, my citations would look like [1,2,3,4,5]. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I am using a custom document class instead of the IEEE class.

This is the code in the parent .tex file

```
\usepackage{chapterbib}    
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
```

This is the code within each chapter .tex

```
\cite{author1,author2,author3,author4,author5}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}    
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibfile}
```

Comment: Because believe it or not, they are manually adjusted by the publication office. See this related one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78108/displaying-in-text-citations-in-a-compressed-way-e-g-1-3-instead-of-the-def

Comment: Unfortunately, not using \usepackage[noadjust]{cite} produces citations that look like [1,2,3,4,5] rather than [1-5]. Also, this is for a dissertation and I won't have any editing help from the IEEE publication office.

Answer (score 1):

With `\usepackage{chapterbib}` and `\usepackage{cite}`, you can customize the in text citation with

`\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}`

`\renewcommand\citeleft{}`

`\renewcommand\citeright{}`

Answer graciously provided by Donald Arseneau

Answer (score 1):

I include the following in the preamble and it compresses the consecutive citations in text.

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

in conjunction with the bib style

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```