# Are there some tools to automate the final submission to IEEE?

Tags: ieeetran, automation, postscript

I got a mail from the editor of the IEEE TEC journal where he explains the procedures which are needed to finalize the submission to the journal:

> The IEEE requires that you submit the following materials through the “Awaiting Final Files” queue in your Author Center on Manuscript Central:
>
> ...
>
> **Separate pages for listing figure captions and table captions.**
>
> **Each figure and table in its own individual file. This includes
> sub-figures. Figures should be identified with the figure number in
> the file name.  Acceptable file formats are Word, tiff, ppt, excel, ps
> and eps.  PNG and JPEG are not acceptable file formats.**

This seems like an error-prone process. So I was wondering if there are some tools that would **automatically generate the required files**.

---

If there are none, I would like to ask if somebody else has gone through the procedure and if they can clarify some details:

1. What is meant by "separate pages"? Does this mean a separate file?
2. How do I deal with captions that refer to equations or figures or contain citations? Do I copy the cited number as shown in the generated pdf?
3. How do I generate a file containing just a table in one of the mentioned formats? Should I use the IEEEtran class with the document containing only a table and then do for example pdf->ps?
4. What if my figures are all pdf's? Should I manually convert them to ps, or does pdf "count" as ps?

It would be also helpful if somebody with insider knowledge could explain the editorial process, so that I can better understand the requirements and make everyone's life easier.

Comment: In summary they say, *we don't deal with fancy stuff*. So anything that requires a little bit of modern packages we don't deal with it and you have to provide externally. Just zip your tables(if any) and your images (converted to eps) with the ,tex file and submit it. Here is my increasing rant about it http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89790/3235

Comment: Looks like the journal is a bit left behind by evolution ;-)