# How to correctly cite more than one reference in IEEE style?

Tags: citing, ieee-style, cite-package

I am using `ieee.cls` and its LaTeX template but I see a problem right away in the citation:
I use `\cite{ref1,ref2}` in my text, and 
I expect to get the following output:
`[1,2]`.

But I get  this `[1], [2]`.

Please explain why is this happening.

Comment: This is 'by design' with the IEEE styles: it's what they want.

Comment: i thought it is my problem. because normally it should be [1,2] not [1] ,[2] !

Comment: related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78108/3235