# How can I keep the font size unchanged while using 'natbib' in IEEEtran?

Tags: natbib, fontsize, ieeetran

I am working a paper for IEEEtran using `IEEEtran.cls`. The citation style is not tidy while citing multple references, for instance,

```
\cite{test1,test2,test3}
% the result is:
[1], [2], [3]

% my expected result is:
[1-3] or [1,2,3]
```

Then, I use the package `natbib` and the citation style is fine. However, **the font size is bigger than usual in bibliography entries**.

**How can I maintain the font size while using `natbib`?**

BTW, the result is `[1,2,3]` using `natbib`. How can I change to `[1-3]`?

The main source codes are as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx} %for automatic line-break in tabular
\usepackage{makecell}  %for table header, center and bold

%
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References}
```

Comment: The IEEE style specifically is to have all numbers including the backets, so the correct for is `[1]--[3]`. That should be what you get from `IEEEtran`: we'll need a full example of your code to help.

Comment: ＠JosephWright, I have edited my question.

Comment: Don't use natbib for `ieeetran` here is a brief why http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78108/displaying-in-text-citations-in-a-compressed-way-e-g-1-3-instead-of-the-def and how to handle citations.

Comment: @percusse awesome. I add the package `\usepackage{cite}` and now the result is `[1]-[3]`, which is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to achieve this, the following code should help you:

Import the `natbib` package as

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Enclose the bibliography with `\footnotesize`

```
\footnotesize{
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References}
}
```

This would

- Make consecutive references like `\cite{test1,test2,tes3}` as `[1-3]`, provided they are not referenced in a different order earlier in the paper.
- Make the font-size of the Reference section as in the prescribed IEEEtran (without a noticeable difference, at the least).

But as suggested in the comments, this really isn't the prescribed IEEEtran way.