# How can I remove comma between two citations?

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I am writing  a paper for IEEEtran. How can I remove comma between two citations? Here is the source code.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}

Text \cite{ref1, ref2}
%The result is: [1],[2]

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References}
```

My expected result is: `[1][2]` or `[1,2]`.

If I use the package `natbib`, the font size of references is changed, which is reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254668/how-can-i-keep-the-font-size-unchanged-while-using-natbib-in-ieeetran).

Comment: Would you consider using `biblatex`, and more specifically, `biblatex-ieee`?

Comment: If you're writing for a conference and they told you to use `IEEEtran.cls`, then leave citations as they want them.